# Python literal_eval invalid syntax

Tags: python, list

When I am trying to do this:

```
literal_eval('[Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]')
```

I get this error:

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was hoping to get a list object like this:

```
[Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]
```

Edit:

Ok, so what I was trying to get is a list inside which there would be string elements. And this was not working because after `literal_eval` the objects inside list were not string.

So, finally to get to my solution I did this:

```
'[Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]'.strip("[]").split(",")
```

This gave the output as:

```
['Alices Adventures in Wonderland', ' and', ' Through the Looking-Glass', ' by', ' Lewis Carroll']
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a list, string items are surrounded with quotes:

```
literal_eval('["Alices Adventures in Wonderland", "and", "Through the Looking-Glass", "by", "Lewis Carroll"]')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = ['[Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]'] #create list that has string literal list
print(x) #observe the list is printed with the brackets as a literal
print(type(x)) #here we are printing the class type of list
```

output

```
['[Alices Adventures in Wonderland, and, Through the Looking-Glass, by, Lewis Carroll]']
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.